# How to hide default context menu item in RCP?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Is there a way to hide/remove/disabled Debug As item from eclipse context menu when you right click a project?

I think this is the extension point to remove but couldnt make sure.

```
org.eclipse.ui.activities
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if debug itself can be removed. But we at Eclipse 4diac are using the activities to hide a lot of menu entries from our users. Below I put you as example the snippet we use in our plugin.xml for deactivating stuff. The hard part was always to find the right pattern, and as I just see the first line tries to deactivate a lot of the debug entries. I hope this helps.

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">
    <activity id="org.eclipse.fordiac.ide.disabledxtensions" name="Hidden activities"/>
    <activityPatternBinding activityId="org.eclipse.fordiac.ide.disabledxtensions" pattern="org.eclipse.debug.ui.*"/>
    <activityPatternBinding activityId="org.eclipse.fordiac.ide.disabledxtensions" pattern="org.eclipse.search.*"/>
    <activityPatternBinding activityId="org.eclipse.fordiac.ide.disabledxtensions" pattern="org.eclipse.team.*" />
    <activityPatternBinding activityId="org.eclipse.fordiac.ide.disabledxtensions" pattern="org.eclipse.jdt.*" /> 
    <activityPatternBinding activityId="org.eclipse.fordiac.ide.disabledxtensions" pattern="org.eclipse.pde.*" />
    <activityPatternBinding activityId="org.eclipse.fordiac.ide.disabledxtensions" pattern="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.*"/>
    <activityPatternBinding activityId="org.eclipse.fordiac.ide.disabledxtensions" pattern="org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.*"/>
    <activityPatternBinding activityId="org.eclipse.fordiac.ide.disabledxtensions" pattern="org.eclipse.ant.*"/>
    <activityPatternBinding activityId="org.eclipse.fordiac.ide.disabledxtensions" pattern="org.eclipse.emf.*"/> 
    <activityPatternBinding activityId="org.eclipse.fordiac.ide.disabledxtensions" pattern="org.eclipse.xtext.ui.shared.*"/>
    <activityPatternBinding activityId="org.eclipse.fordiac.ide.disabledxtensions" pattern="org.eclipse.ui.project.cleanAction"/> 
    <activityPatternBinding activityId="org.eclipse.fordiac.ide.disabledxtensions" pattern="org.eclipse.ui.project.buildProject"/>
    <activityPatternBinding activityId="org.eclipse.fordiac.ide.disabledxtensions" pattern="org.eclipse.ui.project.buildAutomatically"/>
    <activityPatternBinding activityId="org.eclipse.fordiac.ide.disabledxtensions" pattern="org.eclipse.ui.project.buildAll"/>
    <activityPatternBinding activityId="org.eclipse.fordiac.ide.disabledxtensions" pattern="org.eclipse.ui.project.rebuildAll"/>
    <activityPatternBinding activityId="org.eclipse.fordiac.ide.disabledxtensions" pattern="org.eclipse.ui.project.buildLast"/>
    <activityPatternBinding activityId="org.eclipse.fordiac.ide.disabledxtensions" pattern="org.eclipse.xtext.ui.*"/>
    <activityPatternBinding activityId="org.eclipse.fordiac.ide.disabledxtensions" pattern="org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.ui.*"/>   
    <activityPatternBinding activityId="org.eclipse.fordiac.ide.disabledxtensions" pattern="org.eclipse.xtend.ide.*"/>   
    <activityPatternBinding activityId="org.eclipse.fordiac.ide.disabledxtensions" pattern="org.eclipse.xtend.ui.*"/>
    <activityPatternBinding activityId="org.eclipse.fordiac.ide.disabledxtensions" pattern="org.eclipse.xtend.*"/>   
</extension>
```